# Story by a traveler who goes town to town eating interesting meals

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

Inn in each town has an interesting name pertaining to those who travel, i think (am almost positive!) the last Inn was named "The Rest of the Traveler". The author relates his experience, almost as if reviewing the food served in each town, and that the food gets a little worse along the way but still edible. The gist of the stories? Each place is serving parts of people, sending the parts it doesn't use to the next town along the way, hence the name of the final Inn visited.
Driving me crazy trying to remember the title and author of this short. Can anyone help??!??

Comment: Other than this being "horror" themed, what makes this Science Fiction or Fantasy related?

Comment: @Möoz It presupposes the existence of an alternate society utterly unlike those of the real world.

Comment: What was the time frame of the setting? (Modern? Driving his car or riding a bus town to town?) 18th Century Riding a Coach or Horse) Medieval time? (walking or riding a horse?) Was it set in a European setting? Asian? American?

Answer (score 4):

It's not a perfect match, but I wonder if this could be [Curious Adventure of Mr. Bond](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?94245) by Nugent Barker. I read it in his anthology Written with my Left Hand.

In the story there are three inns The Traveller's Head, The Headless Man and The Rest of the Traveller. The eponymous Mr. Bond is the traveller. However Mr. Bond visits the The Rest of the Traveller first, then goes on to The Headless Man and finally The Traveller's Head, where he ... erm ... loses his head shall we say :-)